# How to create a list of random numbers with no duplicates?

Tags: java, random

I need to create random numbers that will run through an array without duplicates.

The problem is the duplication and I can't use any of the utils except the `Scanner` for input (teacher instruction) like `java.util.Random` or `java.util.ArrayList`.

I use a function called `random` that my teacher wrote to us and the function `newNum(int num)` is where I need what I have asked - random numbers.

```
package exercise;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Bingo {

    static int size = 10;
    static int num;
    static int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    private static Scanner sc;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.print("Press Enter to start: ");
        sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("");

        // int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
        // int[] tempArray = arr;

        int num = random();
        // int num = sc.nextInt();

        // System.out.println(num);

        while (size > 0) {
            System.out.println(num);
            size--;
            newArray(num);
            num = random();
            newNum(num);
            // System.out.println(num);
        }

    }

    public static int random() {

        int max = 10;
        double r = Math.random();
        int num = (int) (r * max + 1);

        return num;
    }

    public static int newNum(int num) {

        // Here should go the code for the function for getting only new 
        // random  number without duplications

        return num;
    }

    public static int newArray(int num) {

        int[] tempArray = arr;

        arr = new int[size];

        int x = num - 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            if (i < size) {
                arr[i] = tempArray[i];
            }
        }
        for (int i = num; i < size; i++) {
            if (i < size) {
                int y = i - 1;
                arr[y] = tempArray[i];
            } else {
                int a = size - 1;
                arr[a] = tempArray[size];
            }
        }
        return num;
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. As this is a school project, you really should do it on your own to make sure you are learning. There are also some guidelines around asking questions here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - so if you do want to ask questions, you can do it in a way that makes it easier for people to help. I'll give you a hint on the assignment: keep track of the numbers you have used, and check that list every time you generate a new number

Comment: Thanks for the hint but I need to send it to my teacher till tomorrow so I need more explanation or a quick and explained answer for myself for later.

Comment: Igor, the whole point of school projects is to show that you can do something on your own, and learn what you need to get the assignment in. I could write the code for you, but that wouldn't be right, would it?

Comment: I'm not going to answer it for you, but here's a tip: shuffle the array instead of creating new numbers.

Comment: just a hint - think about something which keeps changing(never remains constant)

Comment: Shuffling is not hard, at least not if you know how, which you can learn soon. Just see [Fisher–Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher–Yates_shuffle).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you write that you can't use shuffle, but that doesn't mean that you are prohibited from implementing it. It's not that hard, actually.

If you want to do that, use the Fisher-Yates shuffle, as found on wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle

(by the way, since you are going to school, if you find such a wikipedia article - or any other article - to be interesting, you might propose to your teacher to hold an essay on that, easily earned additional good grade)

Of course, this assumes that you have a vector to shuffle, which is inefficient for large vectors ("random numbers within zero to one billion"). In this case you might want to go with:

To find n random numbers within 0..m

```
 1. Initialize an empty list of already used random numbers which is ordered, called "numbers"
 2. for i = 0..n-1
      2a: r = random(0..m-i) (uniform distribution)
      2b: for every entry in numbers
          if entry <= r, r++
      2c: sort r into numbers (maybe by using a single bubblesort step)
```

This shifts the complexity from the size of the vector as before to the amount of generated numbers.

Explanation: In every iteration, we want to find an unused number. We find the rth unused number (there is a range of 0..m-i of unused numbers in iteration i). Now we only need to find out which number is the rth unused one. This is done by the inner iteration. We need numbers to be sorted because of this example: current state: numbers = {5, 1}, r = 4. r < 5 -> do nothing. r >= 1 -> r++. End up with r = 5, got a double entry.

If sorting is not wanted for the resulting list, simply go with two lists.